# How can we use SIGHTLY to dynamically populate drop down values(via js file) for "select" html tag

Tags: aem, sightly

How can we use SIGHTLY  to dynamically populate drop down values(via js file) for  html tag

Comment: Post the code that you have done so far.

Answer (score 3):

```
<select data-sly-list="${itemList}">
  <option value="${item}">${item}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Abie's answer is correct, but might need some further explaining:

```
<select data-sly-list="${itemList}">
  <option value="${item}">${item}</option>
</select>
```

Data-sly-list has some default values in its scope and in this case the defaults 'item' and 'itemList' will be used as variable and list name. You can define your own names by adding them to data-sly-list and replacing 'itemList'.

For example:

```
<select data-sly-list.child="${listOfChildren}">
  <option value="${child.name}">${child.description}</option>
</select>
```

More info can be found [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly/block-statements.html#list)

If you don't want to rename them, just as well, just use 'item'.